# GoogleMap: move up TypeControl buttons from BOTTOM_CENTER position

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map into my site, using Google Map Api.
At the position BOTTOM_CENTER are displayed the buttons used to switch from ROADMAP - SATELLITE - and a Custom style.
The question is: How can i move that buttons just some pixels up?

That position is what i need, i just would like to move a bit up the buttons, just some pixels, otherwise the TERRAIN and HYBRID options are not displayed.

If you need, this is the piece of code that manage the buttons:

```
 var myMapOptions = {
     zoom: 13,  
     center: point,
 scrollwheel: false,
 disableDefaultUI: true,

    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
       mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, 'CustomStyle'],
       style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
       position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
      },

 };
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implemented option to achieve it, but it seems that the Map-Type-Controls have a specific className, you may use this class to apply a custom format.

This works for me:

```
.gm-style-mtc{margin-bottom:20px !important}
```